# xcode 10.2 & ionic 3 build error : duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

Any idea what is the problem ?

can't build using xcode 10.2

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 26 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.5.2
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

```
cordova plugin list

call-number 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.2 "Native settings"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.11.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard 1.0.0 "Decimal Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview 1.0.3 "Decimal Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.6.2 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-intercom 6.2.0 "Intercom"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 3.0.1 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sms-plugin 0.1.13 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld build/emulator/***************** normal x86_64
(1 failure)
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -***************** ... ******* ,-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build ios --verbose --buildFlag=-UseModernBuildSystem=0 exited with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was conflict between 2 cordova-plugins.

```
cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview
and
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

I removed cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview and it worked fine.

Comment: Removing the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview worked for me

Comment: I had a similar issue that was resolved by upgrading one of my cordova plugins to the latest version.

Comment: I just had a similar issue and I solved it by removing @havesource/cordova-plugin-push

Answer (score 1):

A thing that should also be noted and fixed the error message on my side, was to delete the relevant folder of the app inside the DerivedData Folder found in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/DerivedData/

Was also mentioned on other similar error messages

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue in 2022, my problem was with `cordova-universal-links-plugin`. Removing this plugin made the build succeed.